# Managing several sets of bookmarks

Tags: bookmark

I have different sets of bookmarks at home and at work. Typically:

1. I want to have access to both at the same time. At work my home bookmarks should not be on my computer (I imagine them on the web, but it could also be on a USB)
2. It should be possible to move bookmarks between the sets, and work with them like 1 set (At home)

At work I use Firefox, at home Chrome. I post here because i think it is mostly a question of finding the right software.

Usecase:
I might have links to threads like this both at home and at work.  I would like to access to them wherever they are.

Also I might to move them between, or do searches over all my bookmarks.
(If my work bookmarks appeared as a folder in my home bookmarks, I could do this)

Answer (score 1):

One possible answer it to use Chrome both at home and work, *assuming that you are allowed to*, and using different Chrome User Identities. The two identities will have their own set of bookmarks but you can easily open a new Chrome window with your other identity - e.g. for browsing at lunchtime with your home bookmarks available.

Your identity is shown as your name in the top left corner of a Chrome window, *(Steve in the example below)*.

[image]

To set up a new user identity in Chrome:

1. Go to chrome://settings/ and look for "People"
2. Select "Add Person"
3. In the resulting dialogue set the Picture and Name and optionally create a desktop shortcut but **do not select** "Control and View..." or shortcuts will not be shared.
   [image]
4. Add or Create a google account, *not your existing one*, by clicking on the new user name in the new window and selecting sign in to Chrome - this will allow you to share your new selves bookmarks across devices.

Comment: Then my private bookmarks is one my work computer.  Also I cant really organize them together.

Comment: I have written a "usecase" at the end of the question.

Comment: Also  Chrome  bookmarks are available at https://www.google.com/bookmarks/, I can also use xmarks.